# How to create a Wordpress, Site-origin widget default or preset image value?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, siteorigin

I am trying to build an stylable widget that loads with preset or default styling values when introduced to a page. I have been able to utilize default=”” within the form fields to achieve this effect on all buttons and text. But I am trying to establish a background image that will load in initially and allow the user to change the image through the provided fields. Is there a way to set a default image value in my field setting to achieve this functionality? I have provided my attempt below to better demonstrate my goal.

```
‘fields’ => [
 ‘image’ => [
   ‘type’ => ‘media’,
   ‘label’ => __(‘Image’, ‘widgets-bundle’),
   ‘choose’ => __(‘Choose image’, ‘widgets-bundle’),
   ‘update’ => __(‘Set image’, ‘widgets-bundle’),
   ‘default’ => ‘exampel.org/wp- 
    content/uploads/2021/05/randomimage_2560x890.jpg’,
   ‘library’ => ‘image’,
   ‘fallback’ => true,

],
...
]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Media Field doesn't currently support defaults at this time. Your best bet for doing this would be to either create a custom field that allows for this, or alter the base custom field using the `siteorigin_widgets_field_registered_class_paths` hook. That hook allows you to override the base form field main file with a file of your choosing so you can use it to introduce additional features or control defaults. The documentation for this filter is still pending, but you can [find the current version here](https://github.com/siteorigin/docs/blob/6ac70cf1ee011f59472602ccf4c4f9b157896eec/widgets-bundle/form-building/overriding-form-fields.md).